# BeautifulSoup is detected but still getting an error

Tags: python, installation, beautifulsoup, pip

I installed beautifulsoup on my macbook using pip but now I'm getting an error when I try to import it that looks like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 175
except Exception, e:
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I suspect I need to use 2to3 since I'm using python 3.4 but from what I've read pip does that without me needing to do anything. Does anyone know how to get around this and if I do need to do a conversion, how would I do that?

Comment: you have installed BeautifulSoup for python2 in your python3 packages, how did you install?

Comment: I downloaded beautiful soup from crummy and then I typed "pip install beautifulsoup" into terminal.

Comment: I've worked it out. As you said, the wrong version was installed for python 3. I had to use pip to uninstall, clear the record of the failed installation and then reinstall beautiful soup.